# Is it possible to use mixed LDAP and local Drupal authenticated users on the same site

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I have a site in which site editors and administrator need to login using LDAP authentication.  However, the site also will have regular authenticated users, who can register for an account directly through the standard new user registration form.  I was wondering if it is possible to configure a Drupal site so that regular users can use the standard Drupal authentication process, but site editors and administrators can LDAP authentication?

I see that the LDAP module has a mixed mode setting in which it will use LDAP authentication if local authentication fails.  I would assume in such a situation, any users that registered for an account through the standard create new account form would have a local account and thus would be authenticated locally.  But how would it work with creating a new editor or administrator account?  Is it the case that I just need to add them to the LDAP server, after which they be automatically added to the Drupal system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any accounts created through LDAP will have access to the site. Alternatively you can create local Drupal users that also have access when using mixed mode.

For instance I work with sites where I have LDAP credentials that allow me access to all the sites. I also had a local Drupal user for one or two that have different credentials and I can log in with either (same email).

Depending on what modules you are using to facilitate this process they may even create a local user for each LDAP user (not sure if they all do this or not). This comes in handy when experiencing LDAP issues as you still have access to your site/s.